# Load JSON file from S3 bucket to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I need to load my data file from `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/easy-client-assets/HomeView.json` and use it in my component.

something like:

```
import Data from 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/easy-client-assets/HomeView.json'
```

any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - load all data from json into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019420/react-load-all-data-from-json-into-component)

Comment: you have to make an api call to get the file from s3 bucket, import only works for local files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loader and configure it to be used in webpack. With webpack >= 2.0.0 you do not need a loader. Webpack will automatically handle the import.
Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) to a loader module.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for your understanding.

xyz.json

// single data
[{age:21}]

// multiple data
[{age:24},{age:35},{age:25}]

```
import data from '../components/xyz.json';

Const parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
// accessing single data
Console.log(parsedJson.age);

// accessing multiple data in JSON
Console.log(parsedJson[0].age);
Console.log(parsedJson[1].age);

// convert Json to string
Console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedJson));
```

I hope it will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

With out some sort of a web pack plugin you cannot reference S3 files with an import statement.  import is for local files only.

I recently solved a similar situation where I wanted to use s3 to host a configuration file.

I solved it with a `useEffect` hook and `fetch` to load the file from a url.  For local development I use `serve` to host a local version and the exact url being a .env config value (and using `dot-env` to handle different build environments).

(note, I use almost exclusively functional react components.  you could translate this to a class component and use `componentDidMount`)

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIG_URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((jsonData) => {
    // jsonData is parsed json object received from url
    setData(jsonData)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle your errors here
    console.error(error)
  })
  },[]) //empty array to get `componentDidMount` only and not have the `useEffect` fire on `componentDidUpdate`
```

This gets the data into the react state and using cache headers limits how often a user grabs the config file.

As for the webpack plugin, this exists but I have never used it https://github.com/egoist/import-http